# On a distributed tensorFlow (1.0.1) chief worker hangs at end of training when using syncReplica and MonitoredTrainingSession

Tags: tensorflow

On a distributed tensorFlow (1.0.1) chief worker hangs at end of training when using syncReplica and MonitoredTrainingSession

Need help to understand what I'm missing. Also, let me know if you need more info

Thanks in advance

**ClusterConfig:**

Number of PS: 2
Number of Worker: 2

**Output:**

**WORKER_0:**

```
INFO:train_opt:Sync Replica Optimizer Enabled...  
INFO:train_opt:[1] Training begins @ 1493747578.942078  
INFO:train_opt:[1] worker/0 1493747581.577683: training step 0 done with Loss 3476.279060  
INFO:train_opt:[1] worker/0 1493747584.819320: training step 200 done with Loss 220.282581  
INFO:train_opt:[1] worker/0 1493747587.935895: training step 400 done with Loss 38.253779  
INFO:train_opt:[1] worker/0 1493747590.975302: training step 600 done with Loss 20.162405  <=== Hangs by end of training
```

**WORKER_1:**

```
INFO:train_opt:Using Train Optimizer: Adam  
INFO:train_opt:Sync Replica Optimizer Enabled...  
INFO:train_opt:[1] Training begins @ 1493747578.956051  
INFO:train_opt:[1] worker/1 1493747581.531765: training step 0 done with Loss 3476.279060  
INFO:train_opt:[1] worker/1 1493747585.027504: training step 200 done with Loss 196.834690  
INFO:train_opt:[1] worker/1 1493747588.469242: training step 400 done with Loss 31.045701  
INFO:train_opt:[1] worker/1 1493747591.898919: training step 600 done with Loss 16.355974  
INFO:train_opt:[1] Training ends @ 1493747612.044738  
INFO:train_opt:[1] Training elapsed time: 33.088687 s  
INFO:train_opt:FINAL Training Loss:11.364212  <==== Training completed on this worker!!
```

```
cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({ "ps": ps_spec, "worker": worker_spec})

server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name=FLAGS.job_name, task_index=FLAGS.task_index, protocol="grpc")

sess_config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=False, device_filters=["/job:ps", "/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index])

if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
    server.join()

elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":
    is_chief = (FLAGS.task_index == 0)
    if FLAGS.num_gpus > 0:
        if FLAGS.num_gpus < num_workers:
            raise ValueError("number of gpus is less than number of workers")
        # Avoid gpu allocation conflict: now allocate task_num -> #gpu
        # for each worker in the corresponding machine
        gpu = (FLAGS.task_index % FLAGS.num_gpus)
        worker_device = "/job:worker/task:%d/gpu:%d" % (FLAGS.task_index, gpu)
    elif FLAGS.num_gpus == 0:
        # Just allocate the CPU to worker server
        cpu = 0
        worker_device = "/job:worker/task:%d/cpu:%d" % (FLAGS.task_index, cpu)

    # The device setter will automatically place Variables ops on separate
    # parameter servers (ps). The non-Variable ops will be placed on the workers.
    # The ps use CPU and workers use corresponding GPU
    with tf.device( tf.train.replica_device_setter(worker_device=worker_device, ps_device="/job:ps/cpu:0", cluster=cluster)):

        # ...build regressor model
        loss = ...
        opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)

        # Between the graph replication. If enabled training happens *syncronously*
        if FLAGS.sync_replicas == True:
            worker_spec = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")
            # Get the number of workers.
            num_workers = len(worker_spec)

            if FLAGS.replicas_to_aggregate is None:
                replicas_to_aggregate = num_workers
            else:
                replicas_to_aggregate = FLAGS.replicas_to_aggregate

            opt = tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer(opt, replicas_to_aggregate=replicas_to_aggregate, total_num_replicas=num_workers, name="nn_sync_replicas")
        train_step = opt.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

        if FLAGS.sync_replicas == True:
            # You can create the hook which handles initialization and queues.
            sync_replicas_hook = opt.make_session_run_hook(is_chief=is_chief, num_tokens=num_workers)

    if FLAGS.sync_replicas == True:
        hooks = [sync_replicas_hook, tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=1000)]
    else:
        hooks = [tf.train.StopAtStepHook(last_step=1000)]

    # The MonitoredTrainingSession takes care of session initialization,
    # restoring from a checkpoint, saving to a checkpoint, and closing when done
    # or an error occurs.
    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target, is_chief=is_chief, hooks=hooks, config=sess_config) as sess:
        while not sess.should_stop():
            # run tensorflow distributed session to compute loss function
            _, loss, = self.mon_sess.run([train_step, loss, ], feed_dict={self.input_features: X_train.transpose(), self.target_output: Y_train})
```

Comment: Any good samaritan, please comment on what's wrong with the code ? Why would chief worker hang by end of training ? This only happens with between the graph replication case. In-graph works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Only the chief will update the variables through the chief queue runner but it should use the grads from all available workers. The chief is supposed to wait until enough grads are collected so not necessarily from all workers.

When `replicas_to_aggregate = num_workers` the chief will wait for grads from all the workers.

In your case as the training is completed on worker_1, the worker_0 (the chief) hangs expecting for grad from worker_1.

You can resolve this by setting `replicas_to_aggregate = 1`. But then I'm not sure whether this will aggregate all grads from all workers when all of the are running.